# selenium new tab in chrome browser by python webdriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am not being able to open a new tab in chrome. My requirement is to open a new tab do some operation then close this new tab and come back to old tab.
The below python code worked in Firefox but not working in Chrome. Could anyone please help me?

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL,body).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Seems that `ChromeWebDriver` doesn't support keys combinations

Comment: This is working with Firefox . my requirement is to open a new tab not by clicking on any link on the 1st tab

Answer (score 9):

Guess this will be helpful:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")
```

This piece of code should start new `Chrome` browser session and open blank page in new tab

Use `driver.execute_script("window.open('URL');")` to open new tab with required URL

Answer (score 7):

I failed to open new tab with required URL by `driver.execute_script("window.open('URL');")`.

Therefore I changed my mind.

Any link will start on the new tab if we consider switching the current window to the new one. And I will open the new tab by `driver.get(URL)`. The only method I need to use is `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])`.

We simply switch the window to the main window, when we close the new tab:`driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])` or `driver.switch_to_window(main_window)`

By the way, it will raise an error if we don't switch to the main window after closing the new tab.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

# save main_window
main_window = driver.current_window_handle

# obtain url of gmail on the home page of Google
addr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gbw"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a').get_attribute("href")

# open new blank tab
driver.execute_script("window.open();")

# switch to the new window which is second in window_handles array
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

# open successfully and close
driver.get(addr)
driver.close()

# back to the main window
driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
driver.get(addr)
```