# Selenium ActionChains Send Keys not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

So this is awfully simple but I just can't get this to work. I can't use ActionChains to send keys to the browser to do something as simple as open a new tab for example.

This is the code, I'm using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL , 't')
actions.perform()
```

I can open the window and go to google just fine but nothing after that.

Editing to add, I've tried IE as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try ActionChains to do something else? In case of opening new tab there is [more simple and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559365/selenium-new-tab-in-chrome-browser-by-python-webdriver/31561107#31561107) to do the same

Comment: My actual use is CONTROL+'s' so yeah I've tried to do other things, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: And what exactly you want to do after "Save file" dialog window opened?

Comment: Use pywinauto to basically save the entire pages html and images. Alternatively hit "Control"+P to print to pdf, again using pywinauto.

Also open to any other better ways to save a webpage with all images intact.

Comment: You can try following line (works in InternetExplorer `driver = webdriver.Ie()` only) `driver.execute_script('document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "filename.html")')`