# New tab using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, webdriver

I want Selenium to check if a window is open in Chrome browser or not, if yes, then open a new tab to the existing window Else, open a new window.

Currently I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

But this does not open a new tab in an existing open window. Kindly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium new tab in chrome browser by python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559365/selenium-new-tab-in-chrome-browser-by-python-webdriver)

Comment: Hi, no.. this opens a new tab, closes -I want to look for is there is already an existing window- if yes, then open a new tab.

Comment: This is unclear, `webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)` will open a new window.

Comment: To check if there is open windows: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: Look for `driver.window_handles`

Comment: Exactly, the code above opens a new window.. What i need is open a new tab on an existing window- just like how a human would have behaved. Window handles would let me switch - but still have to open a window in that session

Comment: @user2458552 Are you talking about connecting to a browser that was opened manually?

Comment: @guy yes exactly

Comment: @user2458552 There are some posts with instructions how to do that, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880646/python-selenium-use-a-browser-that-is-already-open-and-logged-in-with-login-cre), but I never tried it myself so I have no idea if it's really possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly.You would like check if any window is open then you need to open another tab.

For that You need check `len(driver.window_handles)>0` then proceed and then using java script executor to open the new tab.

```
url="https://stackoverflow.com/"
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
if len(driver.window_handles)>0:
    driver.get(url) #proceed with same tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open('{}');".format(url)) #proceed with new tab
```

Comment: This is opening a new window again, and then a tb.I want a tab on the existing window

Comment: Can you provide your code what you have done??.If you see my code its open a window and then check if window exists then navigate url to that window and then open a new tab on existing window.

Comment: I ran the exact code.. But it's opening a window first..It's not checking if I already have chrome open..

Comment: Without driver how this possible to know whether window open or not.

Comment: so, if we run-  import webbrowser webbrowser.open('http://google.com')

Comment: It opens in a new tab in the current window- any functionality with selenium which does the same thing?